# Effect of removing duplicate and identical entries on dimensionality reduction

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-construction

I have huge data with thousands of observations and millions of features. I need to do clustering so I use PCA/t-SNE/UMAP for dimensionality reduction followed by K-Means.

Currently, I retain only unique columns (to decrease redundant features by ~70%) but retain those handful features (<20) that have only one unique value (to save time). Does this process lead to proper feature reduction or do I need to remove rows with single values too? Is there a danger of such columns with 0 standard deviation, however few, to mess up the calculations in some weird way? Please advise.